# Tire - Elasticsearch: Using must with OR across two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to search messages using Elasticsearch and Tire. Everything seems to be fine except that I need to limit the messages returned to those where either the sender or recipient is the user searching. So far it looks like all the examples I've seen handle multiple terms on a single field but I'm trying to OR a single term on multiple fields. Basically something like this:

```
filter :term, sender_name || recipient_name: user_name
```

Putting them one after the other basically creates an AND whereas I'm trying to do an OR

```
filter :term, sender_name: user_name
filter :term, recipient_name: user_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got it figured out. Here's the solution I found which so far seems to work:

```
filter :or, {:terms => {:sender_name => [user_name]}},
            {:terms => {:recipient_name => [user_name]}}
```

Hope this helps someone else!